# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 223: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, django, kubernetes, ascii

I am trying to execute a read file command from command line inside a container in k8s for a django app but i get this error. I am able to execute the same command locally but not inside k8s. My complete error stack is as follows:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/code/setup/management/commands/load.py", line 40, in handle
    raw = file.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 223: ordinal not in range(128)
```

here is the code:

```
with codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            raw = file.read()
        data = json.loads(raw)
```

Comment: `open()` your file by specifying the appropriate `encoding=...`…?

Comment: @deceze i tried changing that but it didn't help

Comment: What exactly did you change how? Show your code. And tell us what encoding your file is in.

Comment: @deceze The file is in utf-8 encoding and i have edited  and added the code above